# XCode project won't build (Terminating app due to uncaught exception)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an XCode project with a main storyboard and main ViewController. There are then 4 sub classes/xib files which can be swiped as pages. This is all working fine, but as soon as I add a label and link it up as an IBOutlet the app does not build successfully and I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ff7cc0953b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key daysCountDaysLabel.'
```

I've been stuck on this for hours and followed solutions from 10 or so similar (and resolved!) posts on Stack Overflow without it working for me.

Things I have tried:

- Making sure there are no IBOutlets that don't match labels
- Removing all the labels/IBOutlets, testing it works and then adding
  a new label and matching up to an IBOutlet (which then doesnt work)
- Cleaning the build
- Checking the source for the .xib files to see if there any old outlets etc
- Making sure class names match up
- Stopping myself posting on Stack Overflow with something that seems easy to fix as there are so many other resolved posts with the same issue (sorry)

I have zipped up the project and placed here in case anyone can identify and solve the issue:
http://expirebox.com/download/87ccb8b70612ef3c86a447ff5eb8d728.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I went through the attached file and I think this might be the problem:

```
let vc0 = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerDays", bundle: nil)
```

You are instantiating a `UIViewController` when it should have been `ViewControllerDays`

So that is why it fails at runtime as its trying to access it as a `UIViewController` which does not have any of these properties.

And this happens in a lot of places. You need to init with the proper view controller class.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it. Although I tried your suggestions and got a new error. What makes me think this part is OK is if you remove the label and IBOutlet the project builds and runs fine

Comment: As @GoodSp33d said. This one of the errors, after that there is a new swift error but for your question this is the solution. I would advice to create a new question with the new error.

Comment: @FriendlyCode, this shud solve your problem. What error did you get? I tried the same way and it worked for me.

Comment: @FriendlyCode think you must have removed the View outlet too. YOu should connect the view outlet to your xib, and everything shud be fine.

Answer (score 2):

sorry I can not able to download your sorce code due firewall restriction. :(

```
1) check all your xib and storyboard you must have "daysCountDaysLabel" label connected and not declared in .h or .m file removed it.
2) window -> projects -> project name delete direved data and try again
```

Comment: Honestly it's not declared anywhere. I know this because if I remove all labels and IBOutlet connections it works. Then when I add a test one it breaks again. I'm working with Swift so no .h or .m - tried the delete derived data but sadly it didn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

So, I see two issues in your project, first of all your xib file contain UIViews instead of UIViewController.Also, they are not linked to your custom ViewController Class. For example, **ViewControllerDays.xib** contains a UIView in which you are adding labels. So, firstly you need to delete that UIView and add UIViewController instead. Then you link that ViewController to **ViewControllerDays**. This was one of the major problem.

Secondly, there is no file's owner to your label, you need to provide that as **ViewControllerDays(or the ViewController in which it is added )**. Hope you understood my point.

**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key** error is answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v).

Answer (score 0):

problem is

```
daysCountDaysLabel
```

find it in project and check outlets/setting text to it

Comment: It's not though - It produces that error for any Label/IBOutlet link up. Download the zip and see for yourself :)